# Append strings via dataframes in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 snippets which are giving me different outputs. The first snippet gives me the desired output but I want to replicate the same output with the 2nd snippet.

Snippet 1:

```
Top= pd.DataFrame({'A':['Hello', 'World']})

insrt1= pd.DataFrame({'A': [f'Appended Item-1x']})

df=Top['A'].append(insrt1['A'])
print(df)
```

Out:

```
0               Hello
1               World
0    Appended Item-1x
Name: A, dtype: object
```

The 2nd snippet yields a different output due to the for loop. How can I achieve the same output as in snippet 1?

Snippet2

```
Top= pd.DataFrame({'A':['Hello', 'World']})

Frst=['1','2']
Scnd=['x','y']

d={}

for num1 in Frst:
    for num2 in Scnd:
        key = f'-OE{num1}{num2}-'
        insrt2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [f'Appended Item-{num1}{num2}']})
        d[key] = insrt2

df=Top['A'].append(d['-OE1x-'])
print(df)
```

Out:

```
     0                 A
0  Hello               NaN
1  World               NaN
0    NaN  Appended Item-1x
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of expected/desired output?

Comment: Desired output is that shown from snippet 1. I want to replicate it with snippet 2

Comment: Are you looking to append rows where column `A` has values `Appended Item-1x`, `...1y`, `...2x`, `...2y`? Please be specific when asking others for help.

Comment: No. I would like just 1 column with 3 rows consisting of ‘Hello’ first entry , ‘World’ second entry and ‘ Appended Item-1x’ third entry with name of column being ‘A’

Comment: I see, putting an answer together for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that's causing undesired output is coming from the fact that you're attempting to append a full `Pandas.DataFrame` to a `Pandas.Series` with the statement

```py
df=Top['A'].append(d['-OE1x-'])
```

If you change this line to:

```py
df = Top.append(d['-OE1x-'])
```

`df` will look like this:

```py
                  A
0             Hello
1             World
0  Appended Item-1x
```

You may want to pass `ignore_index=True` as an argument to your call to `Pandas.DataFrame.append()` so that the row containing `Appended Item-1x` is given a sequential index - i.e the original index of `0` is not included as this would result in two rows with index `0` in `df`.

e.g.

```py
df = Top.append(d['-OE1x-'], ignore_index=True)
```

Will give you the following `df`:

```py
                  A
0             Hello
1             World
2  Appended Item-1x
```

### Alternative Solution

Since it seems that you don't actually make use of each `Pandas.DataFrame` in `d` outside of appending them as new rows to existing dataframes, it may be a good idea to refactor your code so that each entry in `d` looks like `str: str` instead of `str: Pandas.DataFrame`. Using your original code you could achieve this as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

Top = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Hello', 'World']})

Frst = ['1','2']
Scnd = ['x','y']

d = { f'-OE{num1}{num2}-': f'Appended Item-{num1}{num2}' for num1 in Frst for num2 in Scnd }

df = Top.append({'A': d['-OE1x-']}, ignore_index=True)
```

This will also provide the desired `df`:

```
                  A
0             Hello
1             World
2  Appended Item-1x
```

However unlike the previous answer provided (and your original code) it will be much less memory intensive as `d` is not being filled unnecessarily with instances of `Pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: @JP193. Both answers you provide work for me. Now I have come across another problem, details of which I did not include in the original question. It is essentially the appending of another dataframe of numbers after 'Append Item-1x'.

Comment: here is a snippet of my real problem 'df=TOP.append({'A':d['-OE1x-']},ignore_index=True).append
    (df.loc[0].append more.............`

Comment: the error is `cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Answer (score 0):

I think just convert those lists to series and append should do it.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
Top= pd.DataFrame({'A':['Hello', 'World']})
Frst=['1','2']
Scnd=['x','y']
l = (pd.Series(Frst), pd.Series(Scnd))
df = Top.A
for i in l:
    df = df.append(i)
print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
0    Hello
1    World
0        1
1        2
0        x
1        y
dtype: object
```